# Encryption with an algorithm ES256 using openssl

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl, sha256

I need to encrypt some data with an algorithm `ES256`(ECSDA with p-256 and SHA256) using C++ and `openssl`library. How can i do it?

Comment: Please add a reproducible example of code you have tried which is not working. This question does not meet the SO question guide lines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Is OpenSSL a hard requirement? There are libraries with far friendlier APIs.

Comment: I assume you mean ECDSA (not ECSDA). But if so, it is not possible to encrypt data with ECDSA since ECDSA is a digital *signature* algorithm. It cannot encrypt anything.

Comment: Generally, you use AES (symmetric keys) for *encryption* in combination with e.g. ECDH for key *exchange*. Unclear what you're asking.